# How to enforce maxlength on textarea in Opera but allow modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea, opera

I want to limit the number of characters in a textarea to 255 but still allow keys like Backspace, Delete, arrow keys, Home, End, PgUp, etc. I also want to allow Ctrl+C, Ctrl+X, Ctrl+V, Ctrl+A shortcuts inside a textarea. The number of characters should never be more than 255 even when text was pasted by Ctrl+C or right click > paste. With browsers other than Opera, I can simply use the `maxlength` property, but it is unfortunately not supported in Opera.

I looked at some of the solutions of SO, but none of them seems to complelety implement what I want. And those solutions are somewhat ugly because some of them hard code many keyCodes. (Maybe that is the only approach.)

How should I approach this to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Concerning Opera, you can just handle the [`input`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Reference/Events/input) event:

```
$('textarea').on('input', function() {
    if (this.value.length > 255) this.value = this.value.substring(0, 255);
});
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ZCjyA/)

Note: No IE<=8 support. This can technically be shimmed with MS's [`propertychange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536956%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) event, but that's rather buggy when pasting on IE8 textarea, figures.

---

Just made this slightly crude snippet to automatically shim textareas' `maxLength`:

```
$(function() {
    var helper = document.createElement('textarea');
    //if (!('maxLength' in helper)) {
        var supportsInput = 'oninput' in helper,
            ev = supportsInput ? 'input' : 'propertychange paste keyup',
            handler = function() {
                var maxlength = +$(this).attr('maxlength');
                if (this.value.length > maxlength) {
                    this.value = this.value.substring(0, maxlength);
                }
            };

        $('textarea[maxlength]').on(ev, supportsInput ? handler : function() {
            var that = this;
            setTimeout(function() {
                handler.call(that);
            }, 0);
        });
    //}

});
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WwDQn/show/)

Tested in Opera 12.10 and IE8.

This will automatically patch textareas that have a `maxlength` attribute on DOM ready. You may obviously delegate the event (in case there are dynamically generated textareas) by attaching it to an ancestor and using `textarea[maxlength]` as a descendant selector, e.g.:

```
$(document).on(ev, 'textarea[maxlength]', ...)
```

And finally, the feature detection is commented out because Opera **does** have a `maxLength` property on textareas, it parses the value the html to the DOM `maxLength` property as well as having the default value (`-1`) for textareas without `maxLength`, it is just that it apparently has no effect in Opera.

I can't find a way to properly feature detect this Opera bug so the feature detection part is commented out, that is, the code above attaches listeners to `textarea`s independently of whether the browser supports `maxLength`. Feel free to edit the answer in case you manage to feature detect Opera's bug. Though this seems to be a very localized bug that shall be fixed soon enough.

Comment: This is a great answer. Handling input events works perfectly. Thank you very much for your time.